# Abbreviation for "no size" (clothing)

Tags: expressions, abbreviations

In Spanish, when you buy some types of complementary articles of clothing you say that article has no size (*sin talla*). This can be shortened as "*s/t*"; a well-known abbreviation in Spanish (at least in Spain).

*sin talla* articles include cuff-links, and corsages for example. [image]

Is there some well-known and proper abbreviation for "no size" in English, or any other related term, more specific than "one size"? and if not, what is the correct abbreviation for "one size"?, "o/s", "O/S", "o.s.", "OS"?

Comment: I believe your understanding of "one size" is incorrect.  It is a shortened form of "one size fits all" meaning that there only needs to be one size, and that size can be worn by anyone.  A previous comment has links.

Comment: Write that as an answer (perhaps a bit more adapted to be an answer), and I'll mark it as the best.

Comment: @Peregring-Ik: Your question requests an abbreviation, and I do not know of any for one-size-fits-all.  If I were to see "OSFA" or any of your suggestions on a price tag or in a catalog, I would not know what it meant.  My comment merely points out that your objection to the term is unjustified.

Answer (score 5):

A well-known and widely-understood phrase for when something (such as a "size" measurement) is not relevant to an item would be "Not Applicable", which is routinely abbreviated to "N/A", "N.A.", or "NA".

(see "N/A" at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/a) for other references)